# Python : get all the results from a loop , not only the last one?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am running a loop in python , I want the result of every time printed out to a txt file.
But by running my code, only the result in the last time of the loop is printed.
How can I get the whole result?

Here is my code:

```
for tr_list in tw_table.findAll('tr'):
    for p_list in tr_list.findAll('td')[-1].findAll('p'):
        pt=p_list.get_text().encode('utf-8')
    for tag_list in tr_list.findAll('td')[0].findAll('p'):
        tagt=tag_list.get_text().encode('utf-8')
        result = tagt,pt
        result = str(result)
        f = open("output.txt","w")
        f.write(result)
        f.write('\n')
        print result
```

the output.txt should be multiple lines like :

```
result:
123
456
789
```

but the fact is that the output.txt has only the last line:

```
789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `"w"` to `"a"` in `f = open("output.txt","w")`

Comment: yes! you got the point, thank you ! your answer is the most simple one

Answer (score 3):

when you open the file not in append mode all of its content is wiped clean. Because you open it inside your loop you lose all the content except the last result

```
    f = open("output.txt","w")
    f.write(result)
    f.write('\n')
```

You should open the file once. do your loop and close it when done

```
f = open("output.txt","w")
for tr_list in tw_table.findAll('tr'):
    for p_list in tr_list.findAll('td')[-1].findAll('p'):
        pt=p_list.get_text().encode('utf-8')
    for tag_list in tr_list.findAll('td')[0].findAll('p'):
        tagt=tag_list.get_text().encode('utf-8')
        result = tagt,pt
        result = str(result)
        f.write(result)
        f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: Thx, you all helped me with my problem

Answer (score 2):

Open the file *once* and keep the file handle open while iterating:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for tr_list in tw_table.findAll('tr'):
        for p_list in tr_list.findAll('td')[-1].findAll('p'):
            pt = p_list.get_text().encode('utf-8')
        for tag_list in tr_list.findAll('td')[0].findAll('p'):
            tagt = tag_list.get_text().encode('utf-8')
            result = tagt, pt
            result = str(result)
            f.write(result)
            f.write('\n')
            print result
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Your answer are all right for my question!

Comment: This is the best answer because 1) The file is only opened once. Opening/closing the file repeatedly is not good for performance. 2) Because it uses `with(open(...)) as f:`, the file is always properly closed, even if an exception occurs inside the for loops.

Comment: @dano Yes, your comment is quite right , in other circumstances this answer is the most reasonable one!